# OpenShift Python3.3 Cartridge trouble upgrading numpy/installing scipy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, openshift

I have an OpenShift gear with a python3.3 cartridge. On this, I am attempting to install Scipy. I have tried the simplest method of simply putting *scipy* in the *install_requires* field of the *setup.py* file.

This did not work, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.f2py'
```

Okay so perhaps I need to upgrade my version of numpy. I try the obvious again of changing *numpy* to *numpy==1.8.2* in the *install_requires* field of the setup command. This appears to install fine, but I get the same error from the installation of scipy.

Okay, so now I try ssh-ing into my openshift gear (rhc ssh app-name). I try the first thing to simply *pip install scipy*, and I basically get the same error:

```
$ source ~/python/virtenv/venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install scipy
...
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.f2py'
Cleaning up ...
...
```

Okay so I try a *pip freeze*:

```
(venv) $ pip freeze
...
numpy=1.7.2
...
```

Similarly:

```
(venv) $ python
 Python 3.3.2 (default, Mar 20 2014, 20:25:51) 
 [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import numpy.f2py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named 'numpy.f2py'
```

Okay so let's try forcing the upgrade:

```
(venv) $ pip install --upgrade -I numpy
.... success ....
(venv) $ pip freeze
...
numpy=1.7.2
```

Hmm. I try it with and without the *-I* and with and without *numpy==1.8.2*. Each with the same result. Numpy really wants to stay at the globally installed version. Now if I look into the *lib* directory I see:

```
(venv) $ ls ~/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages
bottle-0.12.7-py3.3.egg         pip-1.5.6.dist-info
docopt-0.6.2-py3.3.egg          __pycache__
easy-install.pth            pyparsing-2.0.2-py3.3.egg
Jinja2-2.7.3-py3.3.egg          SQLAlchemy-0.9.7-py3.3-linux-x86_64.egg
lazy-1.2-py3.3.egg          virtualenv-1.11.6.dist-info
...
```

Okay so basically every package I have in my *install_requires* field of the *setup.py* **other** than *numpy*. So now I look in the *lib64* directory:

```
(venv) $ ls ~/python/virtenv/venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages
numpy  numpy-1.8.0-py3.3.egg-info  numpy-1.8.1-py3.3.egg-info  numpy-1.8.2-py3.3.egg-info
```

So basically every upgraded version of *numpy* I have attempted to install (which have reported success). So, how do I get *pip freeze* to see into this directory? I guess more generally I need the *pip* echo-system and python to see the installed packages in this directory.

Or alternatively, what am I doing wrong?